# How do I import python scripts into python scripts?

Tags: python

[image: The picture is where the scripts are stored]I'm trying to import a python script to my other python script because I don't want all the functions at the top of my main script. This may sound stupid because I'm still learning python as well as opencv so please correct me if I'm wrong.

If this isn't the right approach please tell me how I can fix it.

The main code is this:

```
import line_following_testing as lf
from line_following_testing.py import lower_green as lg
from line_following_testing.py import upper_green as lg
import numpy as np
from time import sleep as wait
import cv2
from PIL import Image

green_boundaries = [
    ([75, 52, 60], [106, 255, 255])
    ]

lower_black = np.array([0,0,0])
upper_black = np.array([180,255,45])

lower_white = np.array([0, 30, 53])
upper_white = np.array([20, 180, 255])

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()

    lf.percentage_calculator(green_boundaries, "green")

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    #cropping and getting the hsv value and converting it to see of the value is their
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lg, ug)
    green_result = cv2.bitwise_and(hsv, hsv, mask=mask)

    #cropping and getting the hsv value and converting it to see of the value is their
    mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_black, upper_black)
    black_result = cv2.bitwise_and(hsv, hsv, mask=mask1)
    black_canny = cv2.Canny(black_result, 700,900)

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_white, upper_white)
    white_result = cv2.bitwise_and(hsv, hsv, mask=mask)

    #cv2.imshow("green", green_result)
    #cv2.imshow('black', black_result)
    #cv2.imshow("hsv", hsv)
    #cv2.imshow('img', img)
    #cv2.imshow('black_canny', black_canny)
    #cv2.imshow('white', white_result)


    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k==27:
        break
```

The import script is:

```
import numpy as np
from time import sleep as wait
import cv2
from PIL import Image

lower_green = np.array([75, 52, 60])
upper_green = np.array([106, 255, 255])


def percentage_calculator(boundaries, colour):

    for(lower, upper) in boundaries:

        lower = np.array(lower)
        upper = np.array(upper)

        # finds colors in boundaries a applies a mask
        mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
        output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)

        tot_pixel = output.size
        pixel = np.count_nonzero(output)
        percentage = round(pixel * 100 / tot_pixel, 2)

        wait(1)
        print(colour + " pixels: " + str(pixel))
        print("Total pixels: " + str(tot_pixel))
        print("Percentage of " + colour + " pixels: " + str(percentage) + "%")
```

Comment: You should be more specific with your question - is it working? If so, what's the problem, and if not, what's not working? You may want to consider reading an article that explains how importing works if you're unsure what to do

Comment: Use `import script_name`  .

Comment: In Python 3.x Use `import python_script_name` where python script name should be replaced by just the name of script file without the extention

Comment: use `import fiile_name_without_extension`. But sometimes it may need first add folder (in which you have imported file) to `sys.path` before `import`.

Comment: this is the error message:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\noah.robb\OneDrive - Department for Education\Documents\All_codes\Python\Opencv_codes\line following_v4.py", line 2, in <module>
    from line_following_testing.py import lower_green as lg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'line_following_testing.py'; 'line_following_testing' is not a package

Comment: It seems like you can only import packages in your python files. Try upgrading your python interpreter or maybe changing your application.

Comment: always put error message in question (not in comments) - it will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people may help.

Comment: you have to use filename WITHOUT extension `.py` - `from line_following_testing import ...` - and import will add this extension when it will load file - you use `line_following_testing.py` so finally it tries to load `line_following_testing.py.py` and it can't find it.